# Why is my C++ ATL project linking in a CIL library?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, cil

I am getting this linker error from VC++2013:

```
1>* CIL library *(* CIL module *) : 
error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in mfcs120u.lib(dllmodul.obj)
```

This is a pure C++ project, a COM DLL containing an "ATL simple object", and  "No Common Language Runtime Support" is selected in the *General* project settings. I literally just wizard-created it and it has the same settings as other, working, COM DLLs.

I need to link with the MFC library, not a .NET related library. How could this CIL library possibly end up in the build?

Comment: Generally a header file will specify libraries to link in. Try scanning all the header files you include to see if any of them are the cause.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks. I think the error message is actually misleading, and has nothing at all to do with a Common Intermediate Language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, if anyone needs this for future reference:

This happens when MFC headers are added to an ATL project for which *Use MFC* was not selected during project creation in the ATL wizard.

Reason: The generated `dllmain.cpp` is a bit different for MFC-enabled COM DLLs, but is easily adaptible later when looking at the wizard outputs.

Comment: Any hints on what is different or what to look at when adapting?

Comment: @DougN I don't work with VS anymore, but just create two new projects and compare their `dllmain.cpp` files to see the differences.